# Extra "hidden" characters messing with equals test in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am doing a database (Oracle) migration validation and I am writing scripts to make sure the target matches the source. My script is returning values that, when you look at them, look equal. However, they are not.

For instance, the target has `PREAPPLICANT` and the source has `PREAPPLICANT`. When you look at them in text, they look fine. But when I converted them to hex, it shows `50 52 45 41 50 50 4c 49 43 41 4e 54` for the target and `50 52 45 96 41 50 50 4c 49 43 41 4e 54` for the source. So there is an extra `96` in the hex.

[image]

So, my questions are:

1. What is the `96` char?
2. Would you say that the target has incorrect data because it did not bring the char over? I realize this question may be a little subjective, but I'm asking it from the standpoint of "what is this character and how did it get here?"
3. Is there a way to ignore this character in the SQL script so that the equality check passes? (do I want the equality to pass or fail here?)

Comment: What is the character set of both the source and the target (assuming we're talking about a `varchar2` column)?

Comment: Yes both are `VARCHAR2`

Comment: Hex 96 (decimal 150) isn't a valid 7-bit ASCII character, so its translation depends on which ISO-8859-x encoding you're using, but https://theasciicode.com.ar/ shows it's a u with a circumflex on it. I suspect you're Romanizing foreign names somewhere along the way.

Comment: Extended ASCII says it's a u with circumflex; [Unicode says it's a control character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/96/index.htm], which might make slightly more sense; though it's visible (as a space or ?) when I query it. What does `dump(value, 1016)` report for the source and target? That will show the data type(s) and character set(s) at least. It might also be interesting to add your migration method to the question.

Comment: @AlexPoole Well the migration is using datastage (and not developed by me). I'm testing the results of the migration. Although my SQL is trying to mimic the translation of the ETL so I could provide that. But it's a lengthy CTE query and proprietary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have Windows-1252 character set here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Character 96 is an En Dash. This makes sense, as the data was PREAPPLICANT.

One user provided "PREAPPLICANT" and another provided "PRE-APPLICANT" and Windows helpfully converted their proper dash into an en dash.

As such, this doesn't appear to be an error in data, more an error in character sets. You should be able to filter these out without too much effort but then you *are* changing data. It's kind of like when one person enters "Mr Jones" and another enters "Mr. Jones"--you have to decide how much data massaging you want to do.

As you probably already have done, use the DUMP function to get the byte representation of the data in code of you wish to inspect for weirdness.

Here's some text with plain ASCII:

```
select dump('Dashes-and "smart quotes"') from dual;
```

> Typ=96 Len=25: 68,97,115,104,101,115,45,97,110,100,32,34,115,109,97,114,116,32,113,117,111,116,101,115,34

Now introduce funny characters:

```
select dump('Dashes—and “smart quotes”') from dual;
```

> Typ=96 Len=31: 68,97,115,104,101,115,226,128,148,97,110,100,32,226,128,156,115,109,97,114,116,32,113,117,111,116,101,115,226,128,157

In this case, the number of bytes increased because my DB is using UTF8. Numbers outside of the valid range for ASCII stand out and can be inspected further.

Here's another way to see the special characters:

```
select asciistr('Dashes—and “smart quotes”') from dual;
```

> Dashes\2014and \201Csmart quotes\201D

This one converts non-ASCII characters into backslashed Unicode hex.

Comment: Very helpful info. Thanks.